# What are the differences between the theatrical and extended releases of Dawn of Justice?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

*Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* has recently become available to purchase online. You can purchase either the [theatrical cut](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Batman_v_Superman_Dawn_of_Justice?id=dUPsZxVWeT0&hl=en) or the slightly longer [extended cut](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Batman_v_Superman_Dawn_Of_Justice_Ultimate_Edition?id=cJhKTlZ6tU4&hl=en) for a bit more money.

The extended release contains about 30 minutes of additional footage. Where does this footage fit into the original release, and what parts of the movie does it cover?

---

***Please note: I'm not asking for a detailed recap and/or spoilers, just a general idea of what scenes/characters/plot elements got more time.***

Comment: Well, one's longer for starters. And it's got a different title.

Comment: If you're not asking for any spoilers then why do you want to know what happens?

Comment: I want to know if the new content touches on areas of the movie that I found lacking and thus is worth the extra price.

Answer (score 7):

[ScreenRant.com](http://screenrant.com/batman-v-superman-ultimate-edition-changes-differences/?view=all) compiled a list of all the differences. I won't go through the whole list, but some of the more important changes are:

- The woman from Nairomi, who in the Theatrical version we only see giving testimony at a Senate hearing, is given a more significant subplot. We run into her a few times, and ultimately learn that

  > Lex Luthor paid her to lie in her testimony, to make Superman look bad
- Clark's introduction to The Bat is longer, spanning multiple scenes where he investigates the death of the Human Trafficker branded by Batman. It makes somewhat more sense this way, rather than him seeing one news report and being violently perturbed by it
- Lois's investigations are longer, and they answer several questions that help the film make a lot more sense
- There's a bit of a sequel hook with Lex after the final battle

There are a bunch more changes, with varying degrees of length and necessity, but you can go through ScreenRant's article if you want the full run-down. Most of the additions are either scenes that were cut to dodge the R rating (violence, profanity, substance abuse, nudity), small character moments, or minor clarifying scenes.

The merits of the film itself aside, personally I found the Ultimate Edition to be a better presentation; the plot was tighter, and the character arcs were better-developed. If you're going to buy it anyway, the Ultimate Edition is *probably* worth the money.